# Calculating a weighted average in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been trying to calculate a weighted average but it keeps returning error 1064, does anyone have an idea what's wrong in my sql syntax?

```sql
ROUND (AVG
(`inventory`.`appraisedprice` *
IF (v_winning_clerks.dateentered >= (NOW() - INTERVAL 12 MONTH), 3,
IF (v_winning_clerks.dateentered BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 24 MONTH)
AND (NOW() - INTERVAL 12 MONTH, 2, 1)),2) AS "average appraised price",
```

Comment: Are you *sure* your using SQL Server? That *isn't* valid T-SQL.

Comment: Also are you *really* getting the error *"A filegroup cannot be used with log files."*..? [Errors 1000 to 1999](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/database-engine-events-and-errors?view=sql-server-ver15#errors-1000-to-1999)

Comment: @Larnu It's MySQL

Comment: I was hoping the OP would work that out themselves , @TimBiegeleisen . It's important for them to know what product they are really using,

Comment: I was sitting here like... I haven't use SQL in a minute, but that looks a lot like MySQL lol

Comment: When you encounter an error - post the complete error message. All of it - text, number, any codes, other values returned by the exception etc. This should not be a mind-reading exercise.

Comment: `ROUND(AVG(inventory.appraisedprice * (1 + (v_winning_clerks.dateentered >= NOW() - INTERVAL 24 MONTH) + (v_winning_clerks.dateentered >= NOW() - INTERVAL 12 MONTH))), 2) AS "average appraised price"`

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a balanced parentheses problem.  Use this version:

```sql
ROUND(
    AVG(inventory.appraisedprice *
        IF(v_winning_clerks.dateentered >= NOW() - INTERVAL 12 MONTH,
           3,
           IF(v_winning_clerks.dateentered BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 24 MONTH AND
                  NOW() - INTERVAL 12 MONTH,
               2, 1))), 2) AS "average appraised price"
```